# C# Application and sql database on server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to make an application in c# windows form but I want my database will be hosted on the server. Anyone please help me out how can I access my database using c# windows form application and insert data on the database which is hosted on the web server. Thanks

Comment: -1: This is way too general as a question.

Comment: I need an example of this work.

Comment: You'll have problems getting an example because the questions is kind of too big. Can you get started with **something** and then ask about the individual issues? (Or for that matter, ask how to get started.)

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time, you cannot access a remote DB directly from your app for security reasons (even if you could, it is still better to use a service) and you have to use a service to communicate with it. Take a look at WCF Data Services.

Comment: presumably you mean WCF (not WCT)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Sql Server which is in your LAN, it can be easily achieved,

All you have to do is to enable SQL Browser on your SQL Server, as normal you have access to your local DB, you can access you SQL Server on LAN also..